# Word Location in a file

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

I was experimenting with the Linux terminal and I was wondering how to find the column number and row of a specific word.
For example:

`grep -i "hello" desktop/test.file`

The output was the line containing `hello`, however I also want it to show the column number and row.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, grep can't do that. You'd have to script something out that counted the number of words that didn't match until it did match, and output that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^hello$/) print "row="i,"column="NR}' file
```